# URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I've got a few pages of my site that are coming up in G Webmaster Tools with errors. The pages are fully working, not restricted by noindex or robots.txt file. The pages don'r have a lot of content, but enough to be indexed.

The only thing the Google gives me as a reason when the page is run through the Live testing tool is:

> URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met
>
> - **Discovery**: Not checked in live tests
> - **Crawl Time**: May 6, 2019, 6:25:52 PM
> - **Crawled as**: N/A
> - **Crawl allowed**? Yes
> - **Page fetch**: Failed: Crawl anomaly Indexing
> - **Indexing allowed**: N/A
> - **User-declared canonical**: N/A
> - **Google-selected canonical**: Only determined after indexing

But that's all there is. I can't really find any docs or anywhere about what exactly this error means and what to do to fix it. There are `Learn More` docs, but there are too general that it could be anything.

Does anybody have a similar experience?

Comment: I think you just have to wait.  It looks to me like the page has been crawled but Google hasn't tried to add it to the index yet.  I'll bet that information changes within two weeks.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Pages that are not yet indexed don't come up with error though, do they? If I run the page through the Live Test tool, it returns with Indexing Errors. It says: URL is not available to Google - It cannot be indexed. But I don't have anything here that would be stopping it from indexing, like noindex tag ..

Comment: I'm guessing.  It looks like the page is new and the crawl happened 12 hours ago.  Google probably has a separate indexing queue that runs after the crawl queue.  GSC may not have a good message for pages that have been crawled but the indexer has not run on them yet.    I haven't published pages on my site recently, and none of my pages have similar message.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input, I appreciate that ..

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> Page fetch: Failed: Crawl anomaly Indexing

looks like the underlying problem.

For some unknown reason (a hiccough in the line at your end or theirs), Google wasn't able to fetch this file.
The values in the other lines are consistent with this.

Google will eventually search it again, but you can request that it happen sooner (within a few days or a week) by submitting a <kbd>Request Indexing</kbd> request.

It's only if the page never gets fetched for months, even with explicit requests, that you need be concerned about it.